# Magento 2: Change the product title structure

Tags: magento-2.1, product, product-attribute, title

I want to change product title like below:

> Brand attribute value + attribute set name + guarantee = product title

How should i do it?

Comment: please explain briefly

Comment: @RkRathod want to replace frontend title in product page with this structure: attrset name + brand attribute + model + title + country of manufacture. EX: laptop + lenovo + ideapad + with gift + USA => title = laptop lenovo ideapad with gift USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. app/code/Company/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="training_catalog_product" type="Company\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> 2. app/code/Company/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Product.php

```
class Product
{
    public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        $title = $subject->getAttributeText('attribute_name'); //here you can set product name as per your requirement.
        return $title;
    }
}
```

**get Attribute Set Name :-**

```
protected $attributeSet;

public function __construct(
    ......
    \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSet
    ......
) {
   ......
   $this->attributeSet = $attributeSet;
}


//Build method to get attribute set
public function getAttributeSetName() {

    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $attributeSetRepository = $this->attributeSet->get($product->getAttributeSetId());
    return $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can i get attribute set name?

Comment: update answer for get attribute set name

Comment: Thanks, it works! could you please answer my other questions too???

Comment: add link which question

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287228/magento-2-1-want-to-change-the-product-url-structure

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286024/magento2-1-category-url-structure